# Unable to connect to proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy

I’m trying to use a proxy in NodeJS but I’m getting an error

Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: ipv4.icanhazip.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.packetstream.io, DNS:packetstream.io

Code

```
const request = require('request');
const proxy = "https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@proxy.packetstream.io:PORT";
const url = "https://ipv4.icanhazip.com"
const proxiedRequest = request.defaults({
  'proxy': proxy,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
});

proxiedRequest.get(url, function(err, resp, body) {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  console.log(body)
});
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. The hostname & certificate does not match.

Comment: @Marc and how do I fix it?

Comment: Fix the name missmatch, either change the certifiate or domain name, or create a new certifiate.

Comment: I don't own the domain, it's a proxy service @Marc